# need a software solution to share source files

Tags: .net, visual-sourcesafe

A long, long, time ago, there was visual sourcesafe. What is the current software to integrate into .NET projects? I'm looking for an equivalent solution (software) with similar or better features to lock-in files and brench a file version etc.. It seems that the most recent version is quite old, so I'm wondering what ppl are using now.

**edit**: the project is for some big software on security (banks) and customers doesnt wants to use cloud services but something local that can be integrated with .net visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

The new solution for code sharing is Git, there are some different services for that.

There is [GitHub](https://github.com), where you can post source code for free, but it's open to public. If you wish to make it private, you must pay.

And there is [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/), which is free even for private projects.

They have version control. You can revert your project back to the first commit, to the last changes, etc. It's a really good tool for working with a team.

As mentioned in the comments below you can use [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/), which allows you to run a local Git.

Comment: Another recent competitor is gitlab.com which has unlimited free repositories with an unlimited number of collaborators.

Comment: @Suever i need to install it on a local windows machine

Comment: There is a difference between git hosts and git itself. Git can be completely local. Also gitlab.com actually allows you to install your own instance on a local server

Comment: @Suever thank you for clarification, but in the download page i dont see a windows build, the customer wants to install it on a windows server

Comment: But note, that Git do not support locking files (at least natively). Usually this is not a problem, but if you really need it...